# How to find airline seats with separate recline and back support controls?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, seating

Two weeks ago I flew TAP Portugal and the it was the most comfortable flights I've ever taken! It was in Economy even! This changes everything:

[image]

Normally I find airline seats uncomfortable for a few minutes and painful after half an hour or so due to the lack of back support and the feeling that I am pushed forwards when the seat is upright. Normally I spend most of the flight with a 1-1.5" recline just to relieve the pain.

In this flight though the second control which enhances back support using a pneumatic system made it very comfortable and even handled the seat being upright with any pain.

**How can one find out in advance of doing the booking which plane is equipped with this back-saving feature?**

Comment: I just flew in United business (domestic within US) and it had the lie-flat seats. The seat controls included lumbar support, foot rest, back. Very nice.

Comment: @mkennedy lie flat seats *are* very nice but has ~nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: Related, because the seat had a  lumbar support control which is what OP is looking for. Perhaps I should have said it's doubtful that he'll find out in any other eco class.

Comment: Maybe check out SeatGuru?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there doesn't seem to be such a web site, although there are quite a few that have seat width, pitch, recline, width, leg room, and traveller reviews. With the exception of first and business-class seating, very few have information on features such as lumbar support. For economy class seating, what is available tends to be anecdotal, via customer reviews.

[Seat Guru](https://www.seatguru.com/): airlines, aircraft, seat width/pitch, comparison charts, reviews.

[Seat Maestro](https://www.seatmaestro.com/): search by airline, and craft, along with traveler reviews.

[Seat Expert](http://seatexpert.com/): seating plans, by carrier and specific aircraft, and with reviews but only when one has been submitted.

[Airline Quality](http://www.airlinequality.com/review-pages/latest-seat-reviews/): Customer reviews for seat legroom, recline and seat width, comfort, in-seat power.. and more.

[Expert Flyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/airline-seat-maps): airline seat maps and real-time airline seating charts that show available and occupied seats for a particular flight on a particular date. Combines seat availability with SeatGuru® ratings and reviews.

[Seat Plans](http://www.seatplans.com/): plans for over 150 carriers, limited seat reviews.

[Net Flights](https://www.netflights.com/legroom-chart.aspx), legroom chart and seat pitches by airline and aircraft, seat details including pitches for each seating class.

And, until it's standard, some opt to carry along a lumbar support cushion, such as this inflatable [version marketed to pilots](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/pspages/inflatelumbar.php). Travel shops carry it, as do online merchants like [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_8?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3732051%2Ck%3Alumbar+support+travel&keywords=lumbar+support+travel&ie=UTF8&qid=1492628148&rnid=2941120011).